# How to remove list with in a list if an element in one list is present in the other

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

I have a list containing several lists. The lists may contain integer elements ranging from 0 to 9, if two or more lists have a common element remove the lists of smaller length

```
[[0, 3, 7],
 [0, 3, 7, 9],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
 [2, 4, 8, 9],
 [2, 4, 7, 8, 9],
 [5, 6]]
```

Output should be:

```
[[5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the final expected ouput to the complete problem? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unless he had a short list containing only the numbers missing from his longest list, like `[9]`

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear, I changed the list and added an output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your input lists by length, then take the longest list and add it to the output. Create a set from this longest list against which you test other lists. Any subsequent shorter list that intersects with this set is discarded.

If you find a shorter list that *doesn't* intersect, add it to the output, and update your base set; shorter lists that now intersect share at least one number with the one or more lists in the output, after all. Continue until all lists have been tested:

```
def eliminate_shorter(list_of_lists):
    inputlist = sorted(list_of_lists, key=len)
    outputlist = [inputlist.pop()]
    numbers = set(outputlist[0])
    for sublist in reversed(inputlist):
        if not numbers.intersection(sublist):
            numbers.update(sublist)
            outputlist.append(sublist)
    return outputlist
```

This is an algorithm of O(NlogN) complexity (because of the initial sort).

Demo:

```
>>> sample = [[0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 8, 9], [2, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6]]
>>> def eliminate_shorter(list_of_lists):
...     inputlist = sorted(list_of_lists, key=len)
...     outputlist = [inputlist.pop()]
...     numbers = set(outputlist[0])
...     for sublist in reversed(inputlist):
...         if not numbers.intersection(sublist):
...             numbers.update(sublist)
...             outputlist.append(sublist)
...     return outputlist
... 
>>> eliminate_shorter(sample)
[[0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: @ozgurv: it is a measure of [computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), an upper bound on how many steps the code will perform as N (the length of the input) goes to infinity. I used a sort, and [Timsort has a O(NlogN) upper bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort); that means that the rest of the code, which is a straight O(N) loop will no longer determine the upper bound of how long the code will take to run.

Comment: @ozgurv: if you are going to compare every element in the input list with every other element as aneroid is proposing, you get a O(N**2) quadratic algorithm, every time you add 1 element to the length of the list the computation time would double, while this one would take 1 + log(n) steps longer, a small increase over O(N), which would scale linearly as you add elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [[0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 7, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 8, 9], [2, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6]]

longest = max(l,key=len)
st = set(longest)
print([longest]+[ele for ele in l if not st.intersection(ele)])
[[0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6]]
```

To catch overlapping sublists:

```
longest = max(l, key=len)

seen = set()
seen.update(longest)
out = [longest]
for sub in l:
    if not seen.intersection(sub):
        out.append(sub)
    seen.update(sub)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes but considering the amount of effort supplied I think it is a reasonable answer

Comment: That's what I was trying to say when I saw you had a downvote.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that your solution is correct if there are sublists that only overlap with the `[5, 6]` list. If there is a `[5]` or `[6]` sublist in `l` your code will not eliminate it.

Comment: `[[0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5], [5, 6]]` should produce the same output, `[[0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6]]` but your code leaves `[5]` in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true, I have a fix for that

Comment: Why the two sets now? `seen = set(longest)`, remove `st` altogether, and your code works too. `st` is redundant here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, lol yes indeed, was doing something else originally.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Nested iteration of each list's elements and compare with each of every other. (You get the idea). Probably not the most efficient way.

Option 2: Convert (copy) each of the lists into `set`s. Pick your biggest set `A` and subtract each of the others `B`. If the length of the result of `A - B` is less than the length of `A` then discard the list represented by `B`. If the result has the same length as `A` then all of items in `B` were unique (not in `A`), so don't discard that `B`.